# What books do I need to get all the rules for the Tyranid armies units/formations/detachments?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tyranids

I have the Tyranid codex and got the Shield of Baal: Leviathan supplement but what other books or datasheets would I need to get all of the rules for my army? I would like to get as many of these in physical form as possible.

Also is it worth picking up these books with so many rumors about 8th edition floating around? I stopped playing in 5th but 3rd to 4th to 5th didn't invalidate all the books until a new codex was released. Is this how 5th to 6th to 7th went as well?

Comment: Many of the formations and detachments are only available digitally. There's at least one formation you get by buying the Tyranid Start Collecting box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current main resources for Tyrannids are

- Codex

The Codex is the only one that is needed to run a Tyranid army, but the Shield of Baal series and Rising Leviathan dataslates do provide some additional formations (noted with the [F] below).

Additional resources include:

- Shield of Baal: Deathstorm (Children of Cryptus, Phodian Hive Warriors, The Beast of Phodia, Phodian Annihilation Swarm [F])
- Shield of Baal: Leviathan (Hive Fleet Detachment, Mucolid Spore Cluster, Zoanthrope Brood, Maleceptor,Toxicrene, Tyrannocyte, Sporocyst, Hypertoxic Node [F], Neural Node [F], Skytyrant Swarm [F], Skyblight Swarm [F], Sporefield [F], Skytide [F])
- Start Collecting! Tyranids (Hive Vanguard [F])
- Dataslate Tyranid Vanguard - Rising Leviathan I (Lictor Forest Brood [F], Manufactorum Genestealers [F], Deathleaper's Assassin Brood [F], Broodlord's Hunting Pack [F], Gargoyle Bio-Bombs [F])
- Dataslate Tyranid Invasion - Rising Leviathan II (Incubator Node [f], Synaptic Swarm [F], Skyblight Swarm [F], Living Artillery Node [F], Endless Swarm [F])
- Dataslate Tyranid Onslaught - Rising Leviathan III (Bioblast Node [F], Wrecker Nide [F], Tyrant Node [F], Subterranean Swarm [F], Living Tide [F])

As for holding off to buy them, that's your call. Rumour has 8th Ed dropping around June/July apparently, that said though it will take time for them to update all the current codex's to the new edition, so by no means will they be immediately invalidated.

Comment: This is very detailed, I appreciate all the sourcing. I wish GAW had something that at least told me all the sources of these rules.

Comment: This (https://m.vk.com/sorcererbk) is a nice online resource to give you an idea of what's available before you dive in and buy them

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely wait at this point. At Adepticon (End of March, 2017), Games Workshop, in a closed-door session, announced that 8th edition would drastically siimplify some aspects of the rules. I imagine that will seriously affect the meta. If you have yet to really get into Tyranids, it's a good time to collect models and wait until summer.

Comment: I have an existing army from 5th edition and I am still collecting plastic nids now. Thank you for the heads up about the announcement.